# Read binary file

Tags: java, file, binary

I need help with an issue that i have.
I want to read a binary file.

The content of the file are:
0000000010001100

I'm using the following code to reach my goal:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/test.bin"));
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(is);
System.out.println(din.readByte() & 0xFF);
```

I was expecting that the output was 0, because an unsigned byte of eight zeros is 0. But the code prints 48.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong and explain me how can i have an output of 48 ?

Comment: Look at your file in a hex editor.

Comment: Isn't that just a text file with the characters `0000000010001100`? Do you see them as such when you open it in notepad and like? If yes, then it's definitely a text file, not a binary file :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't inadvertenly save a '0' as the first character in the file?  The ASCII for the text character '0' is 48.